# PCL:NSWindow drag regions should only be invalidated on the Main Thread

Tags: macos, qt, qt5, pcl

I am using PCL to run a test.
Here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(pcl_test)

set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIR /opt/homebrew/lib)
set(Qt5_DIR /Users/kevislin/Qt/5.15.0/clang_64/lib/cmake/Qt5)

find_package(PCL 1.7 REQUIRED)

list (REMOVE_ITEM PCL_LIBRARIES "vtkproj4")
#set(PCL_DIR /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/pcl)

include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

add_executable(pcl_test pcl_test.cpp)

target_link_libraries (pcl_test ${PCL_LIBRARIES})

install(TARGETS pcl_test RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
```

Because VTK in pcl needs dependency Qt5, so I downloaded Qt5 and set Qt5_DIR(I don't use Xcode, but I do have clang).

Here is my cpp code:

```
#include <pcl/common/common_headers.h>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/visualization/pcl_visualizer.h>
#include <pcl/visualization/cloud_viewer.h>
#include <pcl/console/parse.h>
 
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::cout << "Test PCL !!!" << std::endl;
    
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr point_cloud_ptr (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
    uint8_t r(255), g(15), b(15);
    for (float z(-1.0); z <= 1.0; z += 0.05)
    {
      for (float angle(0.0); angle <= 360.0; angle += 5.0)
      {
    pcl::PointXYZRGB point;
    point.x = 0.5 * cosf (pcl::deg2rad(angle));
    point.y = sinf (pcl::deg2rad(angle));
    point.z = z;
    uint32_t rgb = (static_cast<uint32_t>(r) << 16 |
        static_cast<uint32_t>(g) << 8 | static_cast<uint32_t>(b));
    point.rgb = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(&rgb);
    point_cloud_ptr->points.push_back (point);
      }
      if (z < 0.0)
      {
    r -= 12;
    g += 12;
      }
      else
      {
    g -= 12;
    b += 12;
      }
    }
    point_cloud_ptr->width = (int) point_cloud_ptr->points.size ();
    point_cloud_ptr->height = 1;    
    pcl::visualization::CloudViewer viewer ("test");
    viewer.showCloud(point_cloud_ptr);
    while (!viewer.wasStopped()){ };
    return 0;
}
```

CMake can give me a right Makefile , and there is no problem in the command make.
I get the executable file, but when I run it ,it throws up an exception:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'NSWindow drag regions should only be invalidated on the Main Thread!'
```

I don't understand. All codes are in main function, but it seems like that the CloudViewer runs in a sub thread.
I think it may have something to do with my Xcode thing.
Here are my computer config:

1. OS:Big Sur
2. Apple silcon

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that CloudViewer can not be used in MacOS , instead, use PCLVisualizer.